# Error while compiling workspace-d

Tags: d

I tried to install `workspace-d` on Windows 10 using Administrator privilege but failed.

Here is the error message.I haved installed dmd, dub and git.

```
PS C:\Users\U\Desktop\workspace-d-installer> .\workspace-d-installer.exe
Welcome to the workspace-d installation guide.
Make sure, you have dmd, dub and git installed.

Which external components do you want to install?
[1] DCD - auto completion
[2] DScanner - code linting
[3] dfmt - code formatting
Enter a comma separated list of numbers
Selected [all]:
Cloning workspace-d into C:\Users\U\AppData\Local\Temp\workspaced-install-635958600835730563
Checking out v2.6.0
Compiling...
Error: Error writing file '..\..\..\..\..\..\U\AppData\Roaming\dub\packages\painlesstraits-0.1.0\.dub\build\library-release-windows-x86-dmd_2071-92537C3AEFB87AC450BFCCEE2ECBED44\painlesstraits.lib'
dmd failed with exit code 1.
Error while compiling workspace-d.
```

Comment: does it work if you manually clone workspace-d and run "dub build"?

Comment: ok i have pushed a new commit upgrading the dependencies before compiling. Can you pull from workspace-d-installer and try again?

Comment: Yes, it worked.Thanks a lot, but I still wonder why it failed when i was using workspace-d-installer.I'm new to D.

Comment: um..I manually installed it just now, let me try new installer later:-)

Comment: it failed again with the same error...@WebFreak001

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with workspace-d-installer. Even though it just runs the shell commands, it has some permission problems on windows. I have opened an issue on the project page if you want to do anything on it: https://github.com/Pure-D/workspace-d-installer/issues/2

The only solution right now is to manually clone each repository (workspace-d, dfmt, dscanner, dcd) and follow their build instructions. I'm trying to fix that issue so you can use workspace-d-installer.